# Pizza and Hamburger PC game simulator

Tags: gratis, game

**Background:**

Near 2009, I saw my aunt playing a PC game where she was cooking pizza, hamburger and fast food. In this game, customers get mad when their orders are bad made and / or the time used exceeds certain time.<sup>1</sup>

Now in 2015, a few weeks ago, in *The Simpsons* series, I watched a episode called [A Tree Grows in Springfield](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/A_Tree_Grows_in_Springfield) and I saw Homer and Maggie playing a game on his tablet; *a game which reminds me the game that I described above*.

This is the image that I'm talking about (or you can search the specific scene).

[image: Maggie and Homer Simpson playing a cooking game. Source: http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/A_Tree_Grows_in_Springfield]

**Requirements:**

- Operating system: Windows 7 <sup>2</sup> or available version for Android devices *4.1.2 Version or higher.*
- Should be free download *but if there's not free donwload, I'm interested to in buy it.* <sup>3</sup>
- Languages: English (US) but deseable *Spanish.*
- Intenet connection is not required.

**Controls:**

- Mouse (mainly) *because I remember that it was a point-to-click game.*

<sup>1</sup> I suspect that due to the game mechanics, each plate with food has a time span for be prepared and delivered *as indicated in the image sample.*

<sup>2</sup> I don't know the Windows 7 version (but I assumed that it was Windows 7, since she doesn't know how to use PC *someone teach her how to play*).

<sup>3</sup> Indicate cost. I think that the game should not be expensive, *more than $20 USD*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I was redacting the question, I searched on Google the game with this keywords:

> **pizza and hamburger pc game**

The game is called *[Burger Shop 2](http://www.burgergames.co/burger-shop.html)*. I'm not sure yet, but the description match with his first part of the game series called [Burger Shop](http://www.burgergames.co/burger-shop.html).

[image: Burger Shop 2 game. Source: official website: http://www.burgergames.co/burger-shop.html]

And this is a Youtube video with a gameplay: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q7-XxawPI-U

Side note: *The only thing that doesn't match with my question is that I remember well that this game has a level in a kind of "pink" caffeteria and also a cowboy guy.*

*I accepted my own answer, but if someone finds the "pink caffeteria" level or a better option to this game **based on the requirements posted on my question**, I'll consider accept that answer.*

Answer (score 2):

The description you gave immediately reminded me of a somewhat old game about the topic, **Family Restaurant**. In this game you manage a restaurant and have to cook the food for customers in a given time, and success is determined by how much money you earn, according on how good you make the food from a model and how much time you cook it.

#### A few screenshoots:

[[image: Game screenshoot]][]

[image: Game screenshoot]

[image: Game screenshoot]

[image: Game screenshoot]

#### About the requirements:

- Works on Windows 7 (and few other versions too). It also has an Android version and even a Flash one playable on the web.
- Android version is free, web too but Windows is paid with a free trial.
- English language only, I haven't seen any other language anywhere.
- Windows version don't requires internet at all, web one obviously does.
- As pointed out in your own answer, it has pink-based graphics all around.

#### Download links:

- [Windows PC version](http://www.bigfishgames.com/games/2319/family-restaurant/). Free trial available plus option to buy.
- [Android version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funfun4kids.happyrestaurant&hl=es_419) on Google Play official store. Not tried it but comments are not so good generally.
- [Online playable Flash-based version](http://www.agame.com/game/family-restaurant) it's quite much like the normal PC version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately is not the same game, but I appreciate your efforts (+1 for that :) ). Also I'm editing my answer because in the game that I'm looking for is more like  [Burger Shop 2](http://www.burgergames.co/burger-shop-2.html). it has a cowboy guy and another kind of characters, you can se a [youtube gameplay here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q7-XxawPI-U).